# Can I discard eggs?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a load of 2.0km eggs which I don't really care for cluttering up my inventory. Is there any way to get rid of them without incubating them?

Comment: I personally haven't seen any way to do so. Perhaps it's just time to run those 2Ks every day ;)

Comment: Right @Kaizerwolf, this game is suppose to encourage physical movement. Get out of your cars people.

Comment: @Ekmod but how dare these millennials go outside just to stare at their phones all day waaaahhh

Comment: @Ekmod By far the most efficient means I've found for hatching eggs is taking the bus :)

Comment: @fredley really? I thought vehicle transportation was too quick for the game to register the KMs. From what I had heard, biking at a leisurely pace was the best you could do. This changes everything...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Not at the speed they go in London...

Answer (score 2):

No sadly there is no way to discard eggs. You have to hatch the eggs you have before you can get new ones.